# jQuery .css top not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I am dynamically changing css using jQuery:

```
$( "#topHeadVal" ).css('top','7px');
```

It is working fine in chrome. However it is not working in firefox.

I could see the style added to the "#topHeadVal" element in inspect element. But the top 7px is not visible.

In firefox,

[image]

Blue outlined element is "#topHeadVal"

[image]

In chrome,

[image]

How can i fix this?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Working for me See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/sLkg8oLz/

Comment: What more can you tell us about `#topHeadVal`? How is it [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)? Absolute? Relative? Static? Fixed? How about it's ancestors? Also check out: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: insufficient information. needs current code to trace the problem properly

Comment: top, left, right, bottom can only be used if if the element is position relative or absolute or fixed.

Comment: Please tell me this is tabular data and that you are not using tables for layout! Is `id="topHeadVal"` unique or do other elements have the same ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `position` in your element like,

**CSS**

```
#topHeadVal{
   position:absolute; // it can be relative,fixed,etc.
}
```

See [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/sLkg8oLz/)

Or try it like,

```
$( "#topHeadVal" ).css({'position':'absolute','top':'7px'});
```

Comment: who downvoted this? this is a reasonable answer for such a few given information. im gonna upvote this

Comment: @RohanKumar Itz working.. thanks. Before how did it work in chrome alone?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have indicated I would use:

```
$( "#topHeadVal" ).css('padding-top','7px');
```

instead.

Also make sure the id `topHeadVal` is unique, otherwise use a class.